# Selection of radio button in one div based on another radio button in separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two div and having radio button groups with same names & values in both div.
On selection of radio button in first div i want to select radio button with same name and value in another div automatically.
i cant pass name or id manually for each radio group because there are more than 100 groups on page.
How can i do it dynamically?

I have tried in jsfiddle but not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/vp43g7Lh/4/

can anybody help?

Comment: **[Check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/vp43g7Lh/6/)**. This code toggle the check but it will display as only one `radio` checked due to some special reasons or may be the functionality of `radio` button. If you inspect the element if will show the DOM has been changed for radio button but not UI!! so I suggest to use `checkbox` which is more convenient in this case!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add multiple radio groups containing radio inputs having the same name and value. If they are in the same form it makes no sense to add them. You must change the name of the inputs in each group as follows

```
<div>
  <input type='radio' name='o37_field1' value='aaa' />aaa
  <input type='radio' name='o37_field2' value='bbb' />bbb
</div>
<div>   
  <input type='radio' name='o38_field1' value='aaa' />aaa
  <input type='radio' name='o38_field2' value='bbb' />bbb
</div>
<div>  
  <input type='radio' name='o39_field1' value='aaa' />aaa
  <input type='radio' name='o39_field2' value='bbb' />bbb
</div>
```

Here is the demo on how you can update the inputs when clicking one of them: https://jsfiddle.net/vp43g7Lh/9/

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('input[type="radio"][name*="' + $(this).attr('name').split('_')[1] + '"][value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Comment: Please check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/vp43g7Lh/4/

I have two div. and on selection of radio1 in first div, i want to select radio1 in second div too.

Comment: I've answered you above that you cannot have 2 radio inputs having the same name and value on the same page.. The last one will be always checked..

Comment: but if i change name of group then how can i identify which radio group has to be automatically select based on another radio button selection?

Comment: i have tried that code but if i select any radio button with value "aaa" then it select all radio buttons having same value.
but i want to select only two buttons on single click having same group name but in separate div.